# Как сделать постоянно движение змейки?

Tags: c++

Переменные `x` и `y` изменяются только в том случае, если нажата клавиша (одно нажатие - одно изменение). Мне нужно сделать автоповторение. Как его реализовать?

```
    char c;
    while (gameOver == false)
    {
        c = (char)(_getch());
        if (c == 'w') {
            y--;
            dir = 1;
            break;
        }
        if (c == 's') {
            y++;
            dir = 2;
            break;
        }
        if (c == 'a') {
            x--;
            dir = 3;
            break;
        }
        if (c == 'd') {
            x++;
            dir = 4;
            break;
        }
    }
```

Переменная `gameOver` равна `false`.
Так тоже не работает:

```
char c = _getch(); // Начальный "толчок"
    while(gameOver == false){
        if (_kbhit()) c = _getch();
        switch(c)
        {
        case ('w'):
            y--;
            dir = 1;
            break;
        case ('s'):
            y++;
            dir = 2;
            break;
        case ('a'):
            x--;
            dir = 3;
            break;
        case ('d'):
            x++;
            dir = 4;
            break;
    }
    }
```

Comment: Попробуйте убрать все break... Непонятно, правда, как у вас отрисовка устроена. Она же в этом же цикле?

Comment: О сохранении какой конструкции switch идёт речь?

Comment: @vp_arth Извиняюсь, оператор Switch()

Comment: Но в вашем коде решительно отсутствует этот оператор. Сохранить не удалось?

Comment: "Переменная gameOver равна true" - что означает эта фраза и к чему она здесь? Если "переменная gameOver равна true", то ваш цикл вообще не будет выполняться.

Comment: а где `switch`?  То что вы написали прерывает цикл `while` когда нажата одна из необходимых клавиш.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while (gameOver == false)
{
    if (cin >> c) {
       switch (c) {
       case 'w': dir = 1; break;
       case 's': dir = 2; break;
       case 'a': dir = 3; break;
       case 'd': dir = 4; break;
       }
    }
    switch (dir) {        
    case 1:  y--;  break;
    case 2:  y++;  break;
    case 3:  x--;  break;
    case 4:  x++;  break;
    default:
    // не указано как должны меняться переменные если не нажата клавиша. допустим:
    ++x;
    --y;
    break;
    }    
}
```

Не знаю насколько правильно понел что вам нужно...

Comment: @Fat-Zer ,  это зависит от того, что нужно автору вопроса. Ведь мы не знаем, что у него должно меняться, пока не введен  какой то символ из перечисленных.  Или может я не понел чего нужно...

Answer (score 1):

Что-то у меня ощущение, что вы не хотите держать клавишу постоянно нажатой, полагаясь на автоповторение? Если вопрос не в этом - извините, ошибся. Если в этом - то цикл я бы делал так:

```
char c = _getch(); // Начальный "толчок"
while(gameOver == false)
{
    if (_kbhit()) c = _getch();
    switch(c)
    {
        case ....
```

Тогда цикл крутится, пока не будет нажата клавиша. Нажмете - пойдет в другую сторону :)

Но почему бы вам не работать со стрелками на клавиатуре? Как-то привычнее играть ими, а не "буквенными" клавишами.

Вот вам микропрограммка:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    char c = _getch(); // Начальный "толчок"
    while(c != 0x1B)
    {
        if (_kbhit()) c = _getch();
        printf("%c",c);
    }
}
```

Ткните в клавишу - пойдет вывод этой буквы. Ткнете в другую - пойдет другая и т.д., пока не ткнете в Esc.

Comment: Вы совершенно правы, мне необходимо автоповторение. Но вы уверены, что у вас 4 строка записана правильно?

Comment: Надеюсь :) В ответ добавил программку, смотрите сами. Компилировал VC++, работает...

Comment: не знаю, как прикрепить код в комментарий, но в вопрос дополнительно сделал решение, основанное на вашем ответе. Оно у меня не сработало (хочу у вас спросить, что я сделал не так)

Comment: Что значит "не работает"? Вы выводите значения переменных и нажатой клавиши? Откуда вы знаете, что "не работает"?

Comment: я это протестировал в среде. При нажатии клавиш змейка не двигается => переменные не меняются

Comment: В вашем примере не видно использования переменных x, y и иже с ними. рабочий пример я привел. Ваш код я не видел - мало ли, может, вы там как-то не так используете эти переменные. В рамках *представленного* кода все нормально.